# Editable related model fields in Django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

After reading docs of Django admin site I'm still unsure how can I directly add fields of related model in a form by keeping the following rules:

- direct modification of model sources not allowed. Only monkey-patching or subclassing are possible.
- need to insert between existing fields in fieldsets in a form, no in a separate inline admin model
- fields need to be editable, with related model records updated at form save

Simplified example follows:

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms

class Order(models.Model):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, verbose_name=_('Contact'))
    bill_addressee = models.CharField(_("Addressee"), blank=True)

class Contact:
    email = models.EmailField(_("Email"), blank=True, max_length=75)

class OrderAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    fieldsets = (
        (_('Billing Address'), {'classes': ('collapse',), 'fields': (
           'organization_name', 'bill_addressee', 'bill_street1', 'bill_city',
           'email',) })
        #  ^^^^^^ <-- need related model field directly
        )

    class Meta:
        model = Order
```

For read-ony fields that's quite simple task. Just define method returning related model field and put into `readonly_fields` attribute. But what about editable ?

Answer (score -1):

You can simply include Contact.email in the 'fields' list:

```
'fields': ('organization_name', 'bill_addressee', 'Contact.email',)
```

Comment: Tried but getting following error: ```ImproperlyConfigured: 'OrderAdminForm.fieldsets[3][1]['fields']' refers to field 'Contact.email' that is missing from the form.``` . Are you sure you can refer to foreign model field this way ?

Comment: Not working: `Unknown field(s) (foo.bar) specified for Baz.`